# Dynamically Create DataTable from Nested Class

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm trying to create a collection of `DataTables` in C# (.NET 3.5) from a class which contains some nested classes.  I'm basically getting a JSON object, parsing it into a collection of `RootObject`, then will eventually load it into a SQL Server db.  I need a table for each of the Classes below expect `RootObject`, and ideally only the value(?) properties would have a column in the datatable.

Here's a snippet of my classes (my actual classes have between 5-30 properties):

```
public class RootObject
{

    [JsonProperty("BaseOrderShipment")]
    public BaseOrderShipment BaseOrderShipment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BaseOrder")]
    public BaseOrder BaseOrder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BaseOrderShipmentLineitem")]
    public IList<BaseOrderShipmentLineitem> BaseOrderShipmentLineitem { get; set; }
}

public class BaseOrderShipment
{

    [JsonProperty("shipment_id")]
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class BaseOrder
{

    [JsonProperty("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ShippingAddress")]
    public ShippingAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BillingAddress")]
    public BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Lookup")]
    public IList<Lookup> Lookup { get; set; }
}

public class ShippingAddress
{

    [JsonProperty("ship_address_id")]
    public int ShipAddressId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

}

public class BillingAddress
{

    [JsonProperty("bill_address_id")]
    public int BillAddressId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class Lookup
{

    [JsonProperty("lookup_id")]
    public int LookupId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class BaseOrderShipmentLineitem
{

    [JsonProperty("line_item_id")]
    public int LineItemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipment_id")]
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }
}
```

I can get the JSON parsed into a collection of `RootObject`:

```
var obj = ParseOrderShipments(fileName);

public static IList<RootObject> ParseOrderShipments(string fileName)
{
    List<RootObject> retObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

    return retObj;
}
```

My first thought was to just iterate through the `RootObject` class to create a set of empty tables then populate them after I've parsed the JSON into the `IList<RootObject>`.  The other thought I had was to create the `DataTable`'s and populate them at once.  I'm sure this is debatable which is the better approach so I'm open to either.

[Here's a DotNetFiddle Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SWSgU3)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) and [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/). I  think these packages automate do what you need to do. Well, some setup is required, of course.

Comment: So to clarify you want a datatable per object off of your root object? Ie.BaseOrderShipment , BaseOrder , BaseOrderShipmentLineitem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would create a datatable, you can alter the LINQ query to incorporate the properties you require in the table.

```
        List<RootObject> retObj = new List<RootObject>();

        IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
            (from order in retObj.AsEnumerable()
             select new
             {
                 //alter these to build the additional datatable columns you require
                 order.BaseOrder.OrderId,
                 order.BaseOrder.BillingAddress.BillAddressId,
                 order.BaseOrder.ShippingAddress.ShipAddressId
             })
            as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
        DataTable dtbBaseOrder = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```